# Executar comando SELECT em banco de dados Firebird com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebird

Olá, fiz um código pra executar um select em um banco de dados firebird usando javascript, com a biblioteca node-firebird, o código é esse:

```
firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
if (err)
    throw err

db.sequentially(sentence, (row, index) => {
    console.log(row)
}, (err) => {
    db.detach()
})
```

})

o problema é que o resultado desse row, que eu acredito que deveria ser os dados da tabela vem assim:

```
{
  CLIENTE: <Buffer 30 30 30 30 37 37>,
  NOME: <Buffer 4d 4f 4e 54 45 53 20 43 4c 41 52 4f 53>,
  RAZAO: <Buffer 4e 41 59 41 52 41 20 46 45 52 52 45 49 52 41 20 52 41 42 45 4c 4f>,
  ENDERECO: <Buffer 52 55 41 20 42 20 39 31>,
  BAIRRO: <Buffer 52 41 55 4c 20 4c 4f 55 52 45 4e c7 4f>,
  ESTADO: <Buffer 4d 47>,
  VENDEDOR: <Buffer 30 30 30 30 30 32>
}
```

Como pegar os dados de fato ao invés desses "Buffers" ?

Answer (score 0):

O sequentially é para leituras sequenciais.
Você também deve chamar o next(). Um simples JSON.stringify() deve resolver. Sendo assim, seu código ficaria:

```
firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
if (err)
    throw err

db.sequentially(sentence, (row, index, next) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    next();
}, (err) => {
    db.detach()
})
```

Se não está trabalhando com streaming/big data, recomendo trocar o `sequentially` pelo simples `query`. Dessa forma, seu código ficaria quase o mesmo, apenas trocando para o query:

```
firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
if (err)
    throw err

db.query(sentence, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result)
    db.detach()

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Estou com o mesmo problema, mas inserindo o código que Victor mencionou acima também não funciona.

```
firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
if (err)
    throw err

db.query(sentence, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result)
    db.detach()

})
```

Minha duvida.
[Consulta retornando buffer somente no firebird com Node](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/483973/consulta-retornando-buffer-somente-no-firebird-com-node)